# how to get the substring based on length and seperator "-"

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

i am trying to get the substring based on "-", like

ex:a column in data frame

```
ADCSSDKGF
ACD-DDB-RDC-4535
ADD-CDP-2131
DFK-KRD-EEF-CRK-NMC-2342
```

i am trying to update the same column something like

```
ADCSSDKGF
ACD-DDB-RDC
ADD-CDP
DFK-KRD-EEF-CRK-NMC
```

by selecting the string only till last "-"

so far i came up with something like

DF.withColumn("PROMO_CODE",split(col("PROMO_CODE"), "-").getItem(0))

but this is only returning me the first element, i thought of appending the items till length-1 , but i think that will not be efficient ,can some one provide a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------------------------+
|value                   |
+------------------------+
|ACD-DDB-RDC-4535        |
|ADD-CDP-2131            |
|DFK-KRD-EEF-CRK-NMC-2342|
+------------------------+


scala> val mkString = udf((value: Seq[String]) => if(value.length > 1) value.init.mkString("-") else value.mkString("-"))
mkString: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(ArrayType(StringType,true))))

scala> df
.withColumn("data",split($"value","-"))
.select(mkString($"data").as("data"))
.show(false)

+-------------------+
|data               |
+-------------------+
|ACD-DDB-RDC        |
|ADD-CDP            |
|DFK-KRD-EEF-CRK-NMC|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: hey srinivas, thought of the same implementation ,but this won't work when there is a single string something like..ASDADDFFGAA ,this will return empty string wen updated